# laravel oAuth2.0-server error

Tags: laravel, oauth, oauth-2.0

i am using https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel in laravel framework for creating Api's. i configured all setup. when i make a call to get token it shows

```
{ "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the "grant_type" parameter." }
```

My grant type is - 
    'grant_types' => [ 'client_credentials' => [ 'class' => '\League\OAuth2\Server\Grant\ClientCredentialsGrant', 'access_token_ttl' => 3600 ] ],

token is - 
    'token_type' => 'League\OAuth2\Server\TokenType\Bearer', i need sample url for access my api.. whether i need to pass access token where can i get access token.

i dont find any tut about geting access token and use them correctly. please help me on this..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same package with laravel 5. There is this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mshanak/laravel-5-token-based-authentication-ae258c12cfea) that explains it well.

After you publish the package settings, run migrations and add some test data in the oauth_clients and your users tables. Specifically you add client_id and client_secret in the oauth_clients table. Also create a user with username and password in your users table. Finally using POSTMAN chrome extension provide the following data to a POST route to get your access_token.

grant_type as password,
client_id as what you added above,
client_secret as what you just created above,
username your test username,
password your test user password,

You should get correct access_token from POSTMAN.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is to include your `client_id` and `secret_id` parameters
that you got from github when you created your OAuth application. I use socialite and I had used the following information inside config/services.php

```
'github' => [   
            'client_id'     => 'CLIENT_ID',
            'client_secret' => 'CLIENT_SECRET',
            'redirect'      => 'REDIRECT_RUL' 
]
```

Of course that's a temporary solution, if you use laravel 5 I suggest you to save this information inside .env files as they are more secure.
More about [.env](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#environment-configuration) more about [socialite](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication)